# how to make the stylesheet, pictures and javascript files of a custom 404 error page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess

this is my file tree(i am using xampp)

```
                                         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                                   |
REGEXTESTER                                                                         404
   |                                                                                |
INDEX.HTML                                                             ===================
                                                                       |                  |
                                                                     style.css         index.html
```

i am trying to create a custom 404 error page,
MY .htaccess looks like this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404/
```

my 404/index.html looks like this

```
    <html>
<head> 
    <title>404</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../logo.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
    </head>
    <body>
<div>
<h1>How did you get here?</h1>
<span class="second"><h4>I think you need a ride back home</h4></span>
<a href="../"><button>Home</button></a>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

however my 404 works but it only shows text, the stylesheet(even the javascript files and the logo.png) does not load at all
so i tried changing  '' to  
but it only works if i go to a place like http://localhost/REGEXTESTER
but if i go to a place like http://localhost/REGEXTESTER/sdfghjnbvcvbnmmnbvcvbbvcvb the stylesheet still does not load, i need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative paths are relative to the **URL of the page**, not the *location of the file* the page is generated from in the file system.

Since a 404 error can be displayed for *any* URL, you **can't** use a relative path.

Use an absolute path instead. i.e. one that *starts* with a `/`.